# My code runs offline with console.log but not in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

So I am working on my first project and I am only figuring things out as I go. 
I am using an npm module called mal-scraper which gathers data(such as: titles, links for the anime and pictures) from MyAnimeList website and want to create a website which displays currently airing shows using this module.

I ran the code offline and saved it to a variable. It printed out the desired results when called, then I wanted to make cards like so:

```
let count = Object.keys(obj).length;
        //iterate through the obj and create cards
        for (let i= 0;i < count;i++) {
            html += `<div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="container">
                        <a id="link" href= "${obj[i]['link']}"><img id="img" src="${obj[i]['picture']}"></a>
                        <h1 id="title" >${obj[i]['title']}</h1>
                        <p id="date">${obj[i]['releaseDate']}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`
        }
        console.log(html); //test
        return html;
```

This works fine too, but when I try adding it to the index.html with jquery

```
$("#row").add(html)
```

It does not work and I get an error of Cross-Origin something which I don't understand and a CORB warning of sorts. I managed to fix the first with a chrome extension but have no idea how to fix the latter.

Comment: How/Where are you running this script, in relation to the page you are targeting it at?

Comment: Maybe you want `.append()` instead of `.add()`?

Comment: @mark.hch Thanks! .append() seems to work when I create other test cards, while .add() didn't.

Comment: NP! When you use `$()` with a selector it creates a collection of elements matching the selector - using `.add()` will add more items to that collection; e.g.  `$('div').css('color', 'blue').add('p').css('background-color', 'green')` would select all `div` elements, change their text color to blue, then add all `p` elements to the collection, and change all `div` and `p` elements' background color to green. `.append()` is simply to "add" HTML to the end of the selected element - likely why the two are confused. You can also use `.html()` to set the HTML instead of appending to it.

Comment: @mark.hch I do have one question left if its not too much to ask. So in my `app.js`(bundled with browserify) I wrote `module.exports = dataOut` and I want to use this long html string and insert it into the `index.html` file. How could I go about doing that? (`<script src="bundle.js"></script>` is already present in the html and I know something about `$(document).ready(function(){})` just don't know if it should go into the `index.html` or the `app.js` file)

Comment: Unfortunately, my node.js experience is limited - having written only one full application (using the MEAN stack) - and I have not touched browserify. If others aren't able to find and answer your comment, you may want to create a new question specifically for that purpose.

Comment: @mark.hch Okay, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure this is a bit old but since it apperas first in G Search for "...javascript not working offline" here is an obvious yet easy to miss detail.

Using `<script>...</script>` with just the open close tags bare will not garner results. An offline browser is not as smart as some engines which may be running dependency handlers in the background of online servers.

Simply add `<script type="text/javascript">...</script>` to get native support of your browser.

Stick with type=javascript for better offline compatibility, even though most engine talk references using text/application type.

Tested w/ Chrome, FF Beta on Android Lollipop; as local file.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow :)

You may need to fetch the information from an custom backend and set the according headers.

If you dont know how to write a custom backend or just try to play around with it you can use https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/. It tunnels the original requests and adds the headers to allow cross origin request.

The basic idea behind CORS is to prevent other websites request resources from your server without your permission.

More information about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS.

Comment: Thank you so much, now i get the ```console.log(html); //test``` while in the browser. I just have to dive into jquery to properly display them.

Comment: Glad to hear that :) - But you should try it without jquery since the creation of jquery JavaScript it self has evolved and provides some handy features for "jquery stuff"